# Find a circuit implementing a 3-qubit unitary matrix preparing $|b\rangle\simeq(0,c,c,c,c,c,c,0)$ with $c=1/\sqrt6$

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I am trying to find a circuit to represent a 3 Qubit unitary matrix such that $U|0\rangle = |b\rangle$ for $b = \left[0~c~c~c~c~c~c~0\right]$, where $c = 1/\sqrt{6}$.

Although I am working in Qiskit, I cannot use the initialization call, as I need the basic unitary decomposition that creates the state.

Any help on a direction here would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean c=1/sqrt(6).

Comment: Oops, fixing now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's [a circuit for it](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22%7Eo50d%22%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance3%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance3%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Eo50d%22%2C%22name%22%3A%222%3A1%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B%E2%88%9A%E2%85%94%2C-%E2%88%9A%E2%85%93%7D%2C%7B%E2%88%9A%E2%85%93%2C%E2%88%9A%E2%85%94%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D):

[image]

Where I'm using an "odds gate":

$$\text{Unitary}(a:b) = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{a} & -\sqrt{b} \\ \sqrt{b} & \sqrt{a}\end{bmatrix} / \sqrt{a + b}$$

The key idea is to use Hadamards to "double" the number of cases, and the 2:1 starting ratio to get a nice 3-way split after a conditional doubling. That gives you the right amplitudes, but assigned to the wrong states. Then you use CNOT gates to rearrange them into the right pattern.

Comment: I recently found this utility and definitely need to learn to use it! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way with fewer CNOTs:

Assume that we managed to have the first two qubits in the state
$$|\psi\rangle = [0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]$$
Then the required state can be prepared by applying $H$ gate on the third qubit, then applying $X$ gate on the first two qubits conditioned on the third qubit.

[image]

Now, all what we need is to prepare $|\psi\rangle$ which can be done simply using:
[image]

(I got this circuit using qiskit's [`Isometry`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/extensions/quantum_initializer/isometry.html) which uses fewer CNOTs than [`Initialize`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.Initialize.html) most of the time)

So, the whole circuit needed to prepare your state looks like

[image]

Note: after submitting the answer I noticed that it is almost the same answer provided by Craig Gidney.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation.  This is wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the matrix should be something like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
1/\sqrt{6} & * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
1/\sqrt{6} & * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
1/\sqrt{6} & * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
1/\sqrt{6} & * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
1/\sqrt{6}& * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
1/\sqrt{6}& * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
 0 & * &*& * & * & * & * &* \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

You can complete it using the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

---

You can get the circuit and hence unitary matrix using qiskit's `initialize` method as well.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, IBMQ
import numpy as np
num_qubits = 3
c = 1/np.sqrt(6)
vector = [0, c, c, c, c, c, c, 0]
initial_state = vector/np.linalg.norm(vector)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
circuit.initialize(initial_state, [0,1,2])  
# print(circuit)
dec_circuit = circuit.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose()
print(dec_circuit )

          ┌─────────────┐                            ┌───┐┌─────────────┐┌───┐»
q_0: ─|0>─┤ U3(π/2,0,0) ├────────────────────────────┤ X ├┤ U3(π/4,0,0) ├┤ X ├»
          └┬────────────┤┌───┐┌────────────────┐┌───┐└─┬─┘└─────────────┘└─┬─┘»
q_1: ─|0>──┤ U(π/2,0,0) ├┤ X ├┤ U(0.33984,0,0) ├┤ X ├──■───────────────────┼──»
           ├────────────┤└─┬─┘└────────────────┘└─┬─┘                      │  »
q_2: ─|0>──┤ U(π/2,0,0) ├──■──────────────────────■────────────────────────■──»
           └────────────┘                                                     »
«     ┌───────────┐┌───┐┌─────────────┐┌───┐
«q_0: ┤ U3(0,0,0) ├┤ X ├┤ U3(π/4,0,0) ├┤ X ├
«     └───────────┘└─┬─┘└─────────────┘└─┬─┘
«q_1: ───────────────■───────────────────┼──
«                                        │  
«q_2: ───────────────────────────────────■──
«
```

When I used the `array_to_latex` function to get the unitary matrix, I get:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -0.40825 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0.40825 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \\
 0.40825 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & -0.40825 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0  \\
 0.40825 & -0.40825 & 0.28868 & -0.28868 & -0.40825 & 0.40825 & -0.28868 & 0.28868  \\
 0.40825 & 0.40825 & 0.28868 & 0.28868 & -0.40825 & -0.40825 & -0.28868 & -0.28868  \\
 0.40825 & -0.40825 & -0.28868 & 0.28868 & 0.40825 & -0.40825 & -0.28868 & 0.28868  \\
 0.40825 & 0.40825 & -0.28868 & -0.28868 & 0.40825 & 0.40825 & -0.28868 & -0.28868  \\
 0.40825 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0.40825 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0  \\
 0 & 0.40825 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0.40825 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that $1/\sqrt{6} \approx  0.40825$. Also, you need to delete the `reset` operations at the beginning of the decomposed circuit to get the matrix. Otherwise, you might run into an error. One way to do that is just to print out the `qasm` instructions then removed the `reset` operations... then create the circuit with the remaining instructions.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know you could decompose the initialization! That's actually a more complicated circuit than I thought it would be given the symmetry and simplicity of the wave function!

Comment: @Corey The circuit is not optimal. You can probably come up with a more optimal circuit than this.

Comment: U and U3 look like the same generic rotation gate.  I wonder why they differentiate?

Comment: If I understand, the Gram-Schmidth is just going to give me a full (non-decomposed) unitary matrix, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The circuit gate breakdown is more of what I need. How would you suggest I find a more optimal circuit?

Comment: Craig provided a really nice circuit in his answer, as expected.